# Flask web app (using flask to serve a spa website), script not found

Tags: javascript, python, flask, single-page-application

There must be a misunderstanding with me on how the pycharm (debug) server in flask works. Since a very simple webpage doesn't seem to load.

I wish to server the files (even though they're mainly static files) through flask as it allows me to have a bit more control and everything at the same spot.

The flask application looks like:

```
import flask
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import os

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="")


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    m = request.method
    d = request.values
    SITE_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    u = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, "index.html")
    r = flask.make_response()
    return flask.send_file(u)
```

This is simply under the root folder of the project. index.js is also placed under the root of the project:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">-->
  </head>

  <body aurelia-app="rel/main">
    <script src="/testit.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

(Notice it's mostly commented out to simplify things, I've left the comments so one can see the ultimate goal).

The file "testit.js" also exists in the root, with as contents:

```
console.log('in testit.js');
```

Now when I run "index.js" it works fine, pycharm shows the page and the line is logged as expected. The problem occurs when I run the server:
The server does show the webpage (seen by inspecting the source). However developper tools in chrome note a "404 not found" error the "testit.js" file.

So what is going on, I know for sure that file is there? I really do not fancy having to set up an nginx server just for testing purposes when developing. Nor would I like to touch the document structure too much (it's a complicated structure that system.js depends on to find libraries in several different folders).

While not directly relevant to the question, the document structure looks right now like:

```
/
dist/
    rel/
       ... javascript SPA files, refered to by config.js in release
    debug/
       ... javascript SPA files, refered to by config.js in debug
    test/
       ... javascript SPA files, refered to by config.js during unit tests
jspm_packages/
    github/
    npm/
node_modules/
src/
   ... typescript SPA files compiled to dist/ by build tool
index.html
testit.js
config.js
app.py <-- main application file
```

---

On recommendation of  Klaus D I tried to follow the [Documentation for static files](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#static-files). I seem to be unable to understand how this helps though. The `flask.url_for('static', 'index.html')` just provides a file-path. So directly responding that won't actually show the file. - And opening it isn't any different (Or in my case not even working since the filepath includes a leading slash).

```
from functools import lru_cache
import flask
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import os

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="")


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    print("oh")
    u = flask.url_for('static', filename="index.html")
    r = flask.make_response(u)
    return flask.send_file(u)
```

Shows a server error and pycharm's log show "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/index.html'" (file is being server when using 'index.html' through send_file)

When I return "r" and expect flask magic to create a full page, the browser shows simple "/index.html" as response. (So not the file itself, just the filepath).

Comment: There is a section on how to serve static files in the docs: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#static-files

Comment: @KlausD. That doesn't really matter, the html is being served correct. - it's just that the html can't refer to the script files (script files aren't being loaded).

Comment: It matters. Give it a try!

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks for keeping up, but as one can see in my edit it doesn't really help. - Or I'm totally misunderstanding the API documentation.

Comment: I think that you have to prefix `CSS` and `JS` files paths with `/` to get the absolute server's path. i.e  `jspm_packages/system.js` should be changed to `/jspm_packages/system.js`

Comment: @SaidbakR uh, those lines are commented out. - I've removed them now from the post to prevent confusion. (And added the slash in front of `testit.js` for more explicitly, it doesn't work either way).

Comment: you wouldn't have to do alot if you follow have your html file in a `templates` folder and js file in a `static` folder. Then @KlausD. suggestion would be very easy

Answer (score 3):

Just in case somebody is looking for how to do it:

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/singlepageapplications/

This is the suggested code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='app', static_url_path="/app")


@app.route("/heartbeat")
def heartbeat():
    return jsonify({"status": "healthy"})


@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def catch_all(path):
    return app.send_static_file("index.html")
```

If you use a standard-vue-setup for example (build to dist-folder) you should change the second line as following:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="dist", static_url_path="/")
```